# How do I access my Objective-C constants in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

My project currently has a file containing many constants that I use in a variety of places throughout my codebase. I'm writing a class extension in swift and need to access some of these constants.

I have something like this defining my constants in Objective-C:

```
//
//  AppConstants.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppConstants : NSObject

extern NSString *const SOME_CONSTANT_IN_APP_CONSTANTS;

@end
```

I've added my AppConstants.h to the bridging header, but when I try and do:

```
someDictionary.objectForKey(PROPERTY_CALL_CAMPUS_SECURITY_TITLE)
```

I get:

`Use of unresolved identifier 'PROPERTY_CALL_CAMPUS_SECURITY_TITLE'`

Is there a way to access constants defined in Objective-C in my Swift code?

Comment: Put the declaration outside of the `@interface`

Comment: Why not add the constants to your bridiging-header directly, or create a general header and put your constants in there.  They shouldn't go in an Objective-C object's interface.

Comment: Please make sure that the spelling of the constant identifier in `AppConstants.h` and Swift code is consistent with what you've got in the Objective-C code where the constant is defined.